# two fixed div(два фиксированых блока)

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, fixed

Есть два блока(fixed). Как сделать так, чтоб они шли друг за другом(адаптив), они ж не relative?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребят, спасибо, разобрался) раньше использовал top в процентах для 2-го дива, от того и прыгало при изменении расширения. Нужно использовать в 'em'